# Comments on deleted and locked posts should not be able to be edited by their authors

Tags: bug, deleted-posts, locked, comment-edits

[This comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366638#comment1221646_366638) was posted by the author of a question, which was deleted and locked as spam/offensive shortly afterwards. Shortly after the deletion and lock, the comment was edited by its author to ask/rant about their question being deleted as such.

As far as I'm aware, users can't edit their own comments on deleted or locked posts. However, the system apparently allowed an edit on a comment to a post that was deleted and locked.

This seems like this would be open to abuse. The purpose of the lock is to stop *all* interactions with the post from *everyone*; this allows users who commented right before a post got locked or deleted to continue interacting with the post (if they're the author or have 10k+ rep).

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Here's a [screenshot of the comment in question](https://i.imgur.com/SpSoXQW.png) (username obfuscated for (some) privacy) - The post was deleted at 18:57:28 and as you can tell by the screenshot, the comment was posted at 18:56:43. I can't view comment edit history (mods can, though!) so I can't verify when, specifically, the edit took place, but it's definitely post-deletion.

Comment: Oh, great, timestamps prove your point. Thanks for update. (Now I remember the post in question).

Comment: This seems like an extreme edge case. It requires that someone create a comment within a few minutes of the post being locked, the post to be locked, the comment poser to notice the lock, and realize they can edit the comment. Can you explain why this extremely rare combination of events should be fixed?

Comment: Can you address the 5-minute edit grace period for comments in your question? E.g., to make it clear there ***isn't*** a bug that extends the edit grace period to hundreds of years (presuming that is the case).

Comment: @Catija I discovered an additional case where this can be exploited that's not an extreme edge case. When an automatic comment gets posted to a comment-locked post on the user's behalf (automatic duplicate comments and trivial answers converted to comments), the user can edit the comment to contain whatever they want it to say and thus bypass the comment lock. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382171/able-to-post-comments-on-comment-locked-questions-by-triggering-the-trivial-answ

Comment: @sonic, that seems like an extreme edge case to me. This is very uncommon thing to happen. Regardless, I'm not quite sure what you are pinging me here for. The post is already on meta. It's even already status-review tagged. I don't think it's particularly necessary for you to also ping me specifically.

Comment: @Catija Well, you did ask me a question, to explain why this edge case should be fixed. My comment answers your question by stating that there's another less rare case (since it doesn't involve a combination of events that are rare on their own), and fixing this case would also fix that case. I didn't have an answer to your question yet until I discovered that other case, and now that I have, I'm coming back to your question with an answer. The purpose of my comment wasn't to ping you about the other bug - it was to answer your question, which I was late in answering.