# Able to post comments on comment-locked questions by triggering the trivial answer conversion to comment script

Tags: bug, status-review, comments, convert-to-comment, comment-lock

The system has a [feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98955/377214) where if one posts an answer with very short text and an internal link to another post on the site, it will not be posted as an answer, but instead as a comment, telling the user that it's a "trivial answer converted to comment".

However, this feature also works on questions that are locked for comments. It can be used to bypass comment locks to post comments on questions, as one can post an answer that triggers the script and then edit the comment to contain whatever they want it to say. I was able to post [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th#comment1274720_86997) using this method:

[image: Comment bypassed comment lock by triggering trivial answer conversion script]

Note that I took the screenshot after editing the comment; the original content was "this is a test" followed by a link to a random post. Note also the presence of the disabled button to add a comment.

I think this case may have been overlooked since the original lock functionality would block answers to questions, but this specific type of lock no longer does so.

A [similar issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349646/comment-lock-does-not-prevent-automatic-duplicate-comments) was reported for automatic duplicate comments ("Does this answer your question?" comments posted when someone votes or flags to close a question as a duplicate). I think such comments should continue to be posted on comment-locked questions since it's the only public indication that someone's flagged the question as a duplicate, and the user cannot specify custom text for the comment's original revision other than the target, but it should not be possible to edit them after they're automatically posted, since this also bypasses the comment lock.

I'm also unable to delete comments posted as a result of exploiting this issue: when I attempt to do so, I get an error message:

> Comments on locked posts are not eligible for voting

Can this hole please be plugged? The trivial answer script should be disabled on comment-locked questions (either such answers should be blocked entirely with an appropriate error message, or posted as actual answers).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) I can edit this comment all I want, so that would need to be looked in to, too.

Comment: @Luuklag OP mention this as well, but based on wrong assumption that we can't edit such comments. (We always could.)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard that was indeed the point I was proving with my comment.

Comment: And again, this isn't about security, there isn't any risk of hacking into SE or hurting other users in any way. It's just bypassing a lock. Bug, of course, but not all bugs are related to security.

Comment: This seems like an edge case, and if someone repeatedly willfully abused it - probably worth a suspension in my view.

Comment: @Journeyman no doubt but that's not the point, better plug the hole, as OP asks, before it's causing actual damage. (i.e. people abusing it)

Comment: Well yes... I'd retag it but I already beat myself to retagging it :D

Comment: Total aside: being the original author of that question to which you added an answer-converted-to-comment, I also received a notification. I could not upvote the comment though ("Comments on locked posts are not eligible for voting"). :-) It seems I could flag it, but I did not try.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard A subset of security issues are privilege escalation issues, i.e. those which allow someone without the right privileges to do something which they would otherwise be prevented from doing. This one is of that variety since only moderators should be able to comment on comment-locked posts, but this allows non-mods to do so.